How to add points to the diagram of GAM results displayed with the plot_smooths() function?
I cannot add points to the diagram of GAM results displayed with the plot_smooths() function of tidymv package.
I would like to add points to the diagram of GAM results displayed with the plot_smooths() function.
For example;
library(mgcv)
library(tidymv)
library(gratia)

x<-c(0.17,0.19,0.18,0.33,0.24,0.2,0.2,0.19,0.36,0.29,0.24,0.24,0.21,0.23,0.31,0.36,0.33,0.24,0.31)
y<-c(8475,86,209,8230,8372,8475,8475,2867,149,8410,8161,8474,8451,282,7409,682,504,66,315)
dat<-data.frame(x,y)
gam <- gam(y ~ s(x), data=dat)
plot_smooths(gam, x)


I wish to add points to the diagram displayed in this state.
I know that the plot.gam() and daw() functions of the gratia package display points when residuals = TRUE.
plot.gam(gam,residuals = TRUE)
draw(gam, residuals = TRUE)



However, in this case, the y-axis values differed from the actual data values.
I wanted to plot the values of the data usede.
Please let me know if there is a way to plot the data values used in the plot.gam() function or the draw() function.
Thank you in advance.

The easiest way would be to predict from your model to get a nice smooth plot of the estimated smooth function and then add the observed data on top. For example, with gratia::fitted_values() and a little bit of ggplot() we have:
library("mgcv")
library("gratia")

x <- c(0.17, 0.19, 0.18, 0.33, 0.24, 0.2, 0.2, 0.19, 0.36, 0.29, 0.24, 0.24, 
  0.21, 0.23, 0.31, 0.36, 0.33, 0.24, 0.31)
y <- c(8475, 86, 209, 8230, 8372, 8475, 8475, 2867, 149, 8410, 8161, 8474, 
  8451, 282, 7409, 682, 504, 66, 315)
dat <- data.frame(x, y)
m <- gam(y ~ s(x), data = dat)

# data to predict at, evenly in x, 100 values
ds <- data_slice(m, x = evenly(x, n = 100))

# compute fitted values
fv <- fitted_values(m, data = ds)

fv looks like this:
> fv
# A tibble: 100 × 6
    .row     x .fitted   .se .lower_ci .upper_ci
   <int> <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
 1     1 0.17    5349. 1770.     1880.     8818.
 2     2 0.172   5348. 1722.     1973.     8723.
 3     3 0.174   5347. 1675.     2064.     8631.
 4     4 0.176   5346. 1630.     2150.     8542.
 5     5 0.178   5345. 1587.     2234.     8456.
 6     6 0.180   5344. 1546.     2314.     8375.
 7     7 0.182   5344. 1507.     2391.     8297.
 8     8 0.183   5344. 1469.     2464.     8223.
 9     9 0.185   5343. 1433.     2534.     8152.
10    10 0.187   5343. 1399.     2601.     8085.
# ℹ 90 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows

it is a tibble (fancy data frame) that is suited to plotting with ggplot() and manipulation with dplyr etc.
Now for the plot
library("ggplot2")

fv |>
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = .fitted)) + # setup
  geom_ribbon(                      # add credible interval
    aes(ymax = .upper_ci, ymin = .lower_ci),
    fill = "black",
    alpha = 0.2
  ) +
  geom_line() +                     # add estimated smooth
  geom_point(                       # add your data
    data = dat,
    aes(x = x, y = y)
  )

which produces

There are other ways. You could evaluate the smooth (adding on the intercept and a credible interval, and use the draw() method to plot it and then add on the data as above
m |>
  smooth_estimates(select = "s(x)") |> # evaluate smooth
  add_constant(model_constant(m)) |>   # add on intercept
  add_confint() |>                     # add on credible interval
  draw() +                             # base plot
  geom_point(                          # add your data
    data = dat,
    aes(x = x, y = y)
  )

which gets you a bit more info automagically added to the plot if you like that sort of thing

With {gratia} I've focused on two ends of the spectrum

Providing canned draw() methods for the basic plots of smooths, which have some functionality for changing the y-axis scale (via arguments fun and constant in gratia:::draw.smooth_estimates() for example.)
Providing lower level tools so that users can create their own plots with a little ggplot2 knowledge.

The second example I showed is a bit of a hybrid; I used the draw() method for smooth_estimates(), which adds a few things, but you could almost as easily just plotted the object returned smooth_estimates() with:
m |>
  smooth_estimates(select = "s(x)") |> # evaluate smooth
  add_constant(model_constant(m)) |>   # add on intercept
  add_confint() |>                     # add on credible interval
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = .fitted)) +    # setup
  geom_ribbon(                         # add credible interval
    aes(ymax = .upper_ci, ymin = .lower_ci),
    fill = "black",
    alpha = 0.2
  ) +
  geom_line() +                        # add estimated smooth
  geom_point(                          # add your data
    data = dat,
    aes(x = x, y = y)
  )

Once I have got the rest of the package where I want it to be, I do have plans to add more canned plotting functionality and also some ggplot geoms. But I felt it important to first return objects that make it easy to do what the user wants and then build out this other functionality when time permits.

You can achieve this this way:
library(mgcv)
library(tidymv)
library(ggplot2)

x <- c(0.17, 0.19, 0.18, 0.33, 0.24, 0.2, 0.2, 0.19, 0.36, 0.29, 0.24, 0.24, 0.21, 0.23, 0.31, 0.36, 0.33, 0.24, 0.31)
y <- c(8475, 86, 209, 8230, 8372, 8475, 8475, 2867, 149, 8410, 8161, 8474, 8451, 282, 7409, 682, 504, 66, 315)
dat <- data.frame(x, y)

gam_model <- gam(y ~ s(x), data=dat)

smooth_plot <- plot_smooths(gam_model, "x")

smooth_plot +
  geom_point(data = dat, aes(x = x, y = y), color = "red", size = 2)

which gives


Glad it helped. Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted when you get enough reputations. That way, it disappears from the list of unanswered questions.
